# “Not exists” across multiple joins

Tags: postgresql, join, not-exists

I am learning sql (postgres) and id like to find values that do not exist.

I have a table, table 1 with ids and i want to find those ids that are not in table 4.

I have to join between 3 tables as table 1 holds id and table 4 contact_id (not the same number)

The tables 2,3 need to be joined as that connects the ids.

So how do i do that with “not exists”?

```
Select t1.id, table4.contact_id
From table1 t1
Join table2 using(id)
Join table3 using(id)
Join table4 using(contact_id)
Where not exists (
  Select 1
  From table4
  Where table4.contact_id=t1.id
  );
```

It returns no values, but should
No error msg…

I have thinking error i assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query probably returns no values because you join `table4` on `contact_id` and then you exclude in the `WHERE` clause the rows which come from this join.

To find values that don't exist, you can usually use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` and then filter the rows with `NULL` values in the `WHERE` clause.

Try this :

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 using(id)
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 using(id)
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 using(contact_id)
WHERE t4.contact_id IS NULL
```

Comment: As easy as that! Thanks